# Deployment Works when using ftp, but not the domain?. AWS EC2,

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, deployment, dns

So Ive had this practice project deployed for a while, but the issue is now when I connected a domain name to the deployment, it suddenly doesn't work?

the website works perfectly when going to the ip address 18.222.146.180
but when putting the domain thats attached, http://stockstrack.org/ it suddenly breaks and has no css??
I even added other things ive found online into the application file to ensure that it read/attached the css, and still nothing? This whole thing was created with ruby on rails using postgres database. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You have a incorrect virtual host settings, Check again your webserver's virtual host entry.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean... I followed my steps carfully on creating the instance from AWS. Are you refering to this file?       Under /etc/nginx/sites-available, rails.conf                                                                                                           server {
      listen 80; 
      server_name <public_ip_address>; 
      passenger_enabled on; 
      passenger_app_env development; 
      root /var/www/<your_project_folder>/public;
      }

Comment: yes in <public_ip_address> also add your domain name.